# Java Netbeans 6.5 Mastermind Calculating White Pegs

Tags: java, netbeans

For my Mastermind Game I am using 6 numbers instead of 6 colours. Also instead of showing black and white pegs, just 2 sentences are outputted. One reads:

"The number of correct digits in the right position is __ "(black pegs/bothRight) 
"The number of correct digits in the wrong position is __ "(white pegs/numberRight)

For the 4 digit guesses that are submitted, I am using an array called guessArr, which accepts 4 values from 4 input boxes.

```
    guess0 = Integer.parseInt(firstInput.getText());
    guess1 = Integer.parseInt(secondInput.getText());
    guess2 = Integer.parseInt(thirdInput.getText());
    guess3 = Integer.parseInt(fourthInput.getText());

    //New array to arrange guesses
    int[] guessArr = new int[] {guess0,guess1,guess2,guess3};
```

For the answer generated by the computer,

```
    //Create a 4 digit code made of random numbers between 1 and 6
    answerArr[0]=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
    answerArr[1]=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
    answerArr[2]=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
    answerArr[3]=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
```

Finding the amount of black pegs is easy:

```
 //Calculate number of correct digits in correct position


 for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    if (answerArr[i] == guessArr[i])
    {
    used[i] = true;
    bothRight++;
    }
}
```

***EDIT***

I've Solved It!

```
    // Calculate number of correct numbers in wrong position

    //Declare variables for what digits are in the answer
    Integer digit1 = 0, digit2 = 0, digit3 = 0, digit4 = 0, digit5 = 0 , digit6 = 0;


    //Find what the answer digits are
    for (int k = 0; k < answerArr.length; ++k){


    if (answerArr [k] == 1)
    {
        digit1++;
    }


       if (answerArr [k] == 2)
    {
        digit2++;
    }

       if (answerArr [k] == 3)
    {
        digit3++;
    }

       if (answerArr [k] == 4)
    {
        digit4++;
    }

       if (answerArr [k] == 5)
    {
        digit5++;
    }

       if (answerArr [k] == 6)
    {
        digit6++;
    }

  }






    //Declare variables for what digits are in the answer
   Integer gDigit1 = 0, gDigit2 = 0, gDigit3 = 0, gDigit4 = 0, gDigit5 = 0 , gDigit6 = 0;

   //Find the guess numbers submitted

    for (int p = 0; p < guessArr.length; ++p){

    if (guessArr [p] == 1)
    {
        gDigit1++;

    }

    else if (guessArr [p] == 2)
    {
        gDigit2++;

    }


        else if (guessArr [p] == 3)
    {
        gDigit3++;

    }


        else if (guessArr [p] == 4)
    {
        gDigit4++;
    }


        else if (guessArr [p] == 5)
    {
        gDigit5++;
    }


        else if (guessArr [p] == 6)
    {
        gDigit6++;
       if (gDigit6 == 0)
       {
         gDigit6++;
       }
    }


       //Find the value of correct numbers submitted in the guess
       Integer correctNumbers = Math.min  (digit1, gDigit1) +  Math.min  (digit2, gDigit2) + Math.min  (digit3, gDigit3) +
                                            Math.min  (digit4, gDigit4) +  Math.min  (digit5, gDigit5) + Math.min  (digit6, gDigit6);


       //Calculate value of numberRight
       numberRight = (correctNumbers - bothRight);
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :D Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll say up front, I'm not going to give you any code since this is either a learning exercise, so you can learn the language, or else this is a class problem.

So, lets think about this logically...  One way you can you can solve this is by counting the number of a type of colors.

As an example, suppose the player guessed 2 blues, and 2 greens, and the answer has 1 blue, 1 red, and two greens.

The player guessed 3 of the right colors, so you would give them 3 white pegs UNLESS they got some in the right spot.  Now, suppose that they got one of those blues in the right spot, that means they have 1 black peg, which replaces a white peg.  So, the grand total is 2 white pegs, and 1 black peg.

So, to find the number of "Correct Colors" you should check each color (good chance for a loop?) and compare the number of each color that the player guessed, to the number of each color that the solution has.

Put another way, you don't want to compare the guess to the answer.  You want to compare the count for each color on the guess, to the count of each color on the solution.

Then, you get "White pegs" by this pesudo-code:
int whitePegs=correctColors-blackPegs;

Edit 1: **Comparing answers one color at a time**

If you're going to hold the count for each color, then you're going to want to use two arrays, one for the guess, and one for the solution.  Each element in the array will hold the count for the color, like this:

```
r=red, o=orange, y=yellow, etc.
         R  O  Y  G  B
Guess:  [0][2][1][1][0] (Total is 4, for 4 pegs
Actual: [1][1][2][0][0] (Total is 4) for 4 pegs
Matches:[0][1][1][0][0] (Total is 2) This is "correctColors" from above
```

Comment: Yes, it's for a Gr.11 Intro to Java Summative Assignment. Do you mean a loop for each colour? So 6 loops? Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Also, how exactly would I determine which colours to test for in the loop? Would I somehow have to find the numbers that are in the generated answer? Thank you.

Comment: It seems the biggest hurdle to understand is: checking each digit  and comparing the number of each digit that the player guessed, to the number of each digit that the solution has. Thank you, and yes I know I am a newbie.

Comment: Like This?   for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
      {
          if (answerArr [j] == 1)

        {
            Integer digit1 = 0;
            digit1++;
               
        }
      }

Comment: @AlexKwan Take a look at what I just edited into the bottom.  It has a graphical representation of the two arrays that contain the "color counts".

Comment: Ahh that edit really clarified the concept.. I'm just wondering how would I be able to retrieve that info from the guesses and answers, like actually find how many 1,2,3,4,5, or/ and 6's are in the guess or answer. Would I use a For loop? Thank you, your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @AlexKwan Short answer:  Yes, I would use a loop.  You want to loop through the "guess" array.  So, I would use something like this as the start of my for loop (Note: probably isn't correct syntax.  I've been using C# too much recently): for( int i=0; i<answerArr.length; ++i)

Comment: Okay, should be done this in 10minutes. Will report back then. Thank you very much my good sir!

Comment: One Question:            Integer correctNumbers = (gDigit1 - digit1) + (gDigit2 - digit2) + (gDigit3 - digit3) + (gDigit4 - digit4)
                                        + (gDigit5 - digit5) + (gDigit6 - digit6);     The value of correctNumbers will always be 0, how do i make so that when it a guess digit doesnt exist and is subtracted by a value of 1 (eg) from the answer value that it doesnt go -1?

           numberRight = correctNumbers - bothRight;

Comment: I guess a whole bunch of if gDigit(#) = 0 then digit(#) = 0?

Comment: @AlexKwan In answer to the first question...  The function Math.min(int,int) is your friend.  To answer your second question...  That doesn't work.  You would need if(gDigit[#] == 0) then {gDigitCount[0]++} else if(gDigit[#] == 1) ...  Except, there's a nicer way...  In fact, you can replace that mess inside of the for loop with one line of code...  It doesn't even require any if, switch, for, while, or control logic or function calls...

Comment: Okay I'm back now (stayed up till 3am last night, it 2pm in Canada right now). Will try that. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, where would I use the Math.min function? Should I use it in comparing the value of the answer digits and checking to see if there is guess digit that is the same? Eg. If answer contains 3, but guess doesn't contain 3, then i find the minimum of 0 and use 0 in the correctNumbers variable? Thanks.

Comment: In regards to my last post: Also on the flipside, how would I sort out guess digits that are guessed, but don't exist in the answer (digit doesn't exist in answer)? As that would also not warrant a white peg.

Comment: EUREKA! I've GOT IT!!!! OMG TY TY TY!!! Posted the solution in the EDIT of my question